# Angular 2 import modules using absolute path with webpack

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack-2

I am trying to implement the `absolute path` in `angular 2` using `webpack 2`.

**I had a look on this [article](https://moduscreate.com/es6-es2015-import-no-relative-path-webpack/) which is showing how to use the absolute path.**

I have the folder structure as:

```
|-resources
   |-assets
      |-Typescript
         |-main.ts
         |-App
            |-app.module.ts
|-Modules
   |-Core
      |-Assets
         |-Typescript
            |-core.module.ts
   |-Cart
      |-Assets
         |-Typescript
            |-cart.module.ts
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './App/AppModule';
if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CoreModule } from '../../../../Modules/Core/Assets/Typescript/core.module';
import { CartModule } from '../../../../Modules/Cart/Assets/Typescript/cart.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CoreModule,
        CartModule
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**webpack.common.js** consists of the resolve configuration

```
resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: [helpers.root('./resources/assets/Typescript'), helpers.root('./Modules'),'node_modules'],
        },
```

**helpers.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

function root(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
}

exports.root = root;
```

**When i try to use Modules/Core/Assets/Typescript/core.module in app.module.ts** I get:

```
ERROR in [default] C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\assets\Typescript\App\AppModule.ts:3:27
Cannot find module 'Modules/Core/Assets/Typescript/core.module'.
```

How could i implement the `absolute path in the custom directory`?. **Adding the Modules directory inside the node_modules gives me the correct directory path for the imports** but it is not the thing that we all wants to do.

Comment: There is a relevant discussion, which highlights some issues with TypeScript config after modifying the WebPack config - https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/1439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but it is not the good way to do the imports.

**Add the root directory to the modules resolver in webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: [helpers.root('./resources/assets/Typescript'), helpers.root('./Modules'),'node_modules'],
        },
```

**In app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './Components/AppComponent';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        require('Core/Assets/Typescript/Core/CoreModule').CoreModule,
        require('Category/Assets/Typescript/Category/CategoryModule').CategoryModule
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AdminModule {}
```

The main thing is add only the `root directory` from where you want to use the path and it will work.